# Как задать фиксированную высоту первой строки таблицы и отцентровать значения в ячейках?

Tags: html, css, table

Мне надо задать фиксированную высоту ячеек в первой строке таблицы (допустим, `45px`). После этого надо отцентрировать значения внутри ячеек: как по горизонтали, так и по вертикали.

Вот первая строка таблицы:

```css
.text-center > th {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<tr class="font-size-12 text-center">
    <th>№</th>
    <th>Период</th>
    <th>Исходные значения</th>
    <th>Модельные значения</th>
</tr>
```

Но не понимаю, где задавать высоту ячейки. Если в каком-нибудь из `th`, то центрирование по вертикали не работает и получается так:

[image: скрин]

Comment: Вы используйте `bootstrap`?

Answer (score 1):

Должно работать.

https://codepen.io/laser_beard/pen/bRrYRr

У тебя видимо какой-то другой css на это влияет. Посмотри в инспекторе `line-height`, `vertical-align`, `display`, `padding` для `th`. Может что-то перекрывает

Answer (score 0):

В спецификации сказанно что тег`<th>` используется в двух колончатых таблицах, а судя по скриншоту у Вас их больше,Вы представили лишь часть кода и от сюда не ясности, попробуйте изменить `<th>` на `<td>` 
 Или, как вариант, для  `<th>` указать не `vertical-align` а `valign` с значением `middle`.
 Кстати имейте в виду, что `<th>`не поддерживается в HTML5